# Not able to access rabbitMQ installed in docker

Tags: spring, docker, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have installed rabbit MQ in docker, my host machine OS is windows. Now I am not able to access rabbit mq instance present in my docker but others can access the same using my Ip address. While trying to connect using spring boot amqp I am getting error

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException .....
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null .....
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error....
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.....
```

Comment: _"but others can access the same using my Ip"_ what does that mean?

Comment: Look at the server log in the docker image.

Comment: can you share the docker file, run steps and url used in your spring boot app?

Comment: Just wondering. when you say you can't access, is it by any chance while trying on localhost (127.0.0.1)?
Would explain the `others can access` aspect.